# How to call a function without passing all parameters to it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

- I have a function with 4 parameters.
- When I call it sometimes I don't
  have all 4 parameters to pass to it, so I want to pass only 1,2, or 3 parameters instead.

Unity shows an error in this case. how can I mark these parameters as "optional", or is there any better solution?

Example:

```
void example(Texture texture1, Texture texture2, Texture texture3, Texture texture4) {

  renderer1.material.mainTexture = texture1;

  if (texture2 != null) {
    renderer2.material.mainTexture = texture2;
  }
  if (texture3 != null) {
    renderer3.material.mainTexture = texture3;
  }
  if (texture4 != null) {
    renderer4.material.mainTexture = texture4;
  }

}

    public void callExample(){
    example(texture1, texture2);
};
```

Comment: Set default values of say null as what you test for but you woukd need to know if you provided 2 parameters it would need to be the first 2 it cant be say 1 and 4. Or you overload the function

Comment: @BugFinder thank you for the advice. Yes, that's what I need, if I pass 1 parameter I want it to be the 1st one, if 2 - the first 2, etc. What do you mean by overloading the function? How can I set default values?

Comment: @BugFinder Is it a good practice in general, or would you suggest some different solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make argument optional you should provide default value, just like this:

```csharp
void example(Texture texture1, Texture texture2 = null, Texture texture3 = null, Texture texture4 = null) {
```